# When do changes to Lambda environment variables take effect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Suppose I add or change the value of an existing environment variable. When does the change effect?

Will it only take effect new execution environments (cold starts), or will it also take effect for existing execution environments (warm invocations)?

> Environment variables are not evaluated before the function
> invocation. Any value you define is considered a literal string and
> not expanded. Perform the variable evaluation in your function code.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html

Comment: It's not explicitly called out, but I imagine that environment variables fall under "configuration" so they take effect at cold start time https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/execution-environments.html

Comment: OK, so existing execution environments won't be affected, i.e. warm executions for those environments will use the old values? Is there any way to delete existing execution environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will it only take effect new execution environments (cold starts), or will it also take effect for existing execution environments (warm invocations)?

Only during the cold starts.

Changing environment variables (as well as memory settings, CPU requirements and other parameters) creates a new *revision* of the Lambda, which requires a new instance of execution environment.

Revision is an immutable transient reference to a definition of the Lambda, complete with its code, environment variables and execution environment. When you change something in a Lambda, the old revision is gone, but the environments that are currently executing it will continue executing.

Revision id is returned by several API endpoints (such as [`GetFunction`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_GetFunction.html)). Most methods that create new revisions also accept a reference to the old one to ensure compare-and-swap semantics.

You can turn a revision into a function version (a permanent reference to a definition of Lambda that you can explicitly invoke).

Comment: Excellent answer, so a revision ID is a reference (or an ID) to a definition of Lambda function? Each time I change a setting of Lambda function e.g. memory, environment variables, etc. it creates a new revision of the function? The unpublished version ($LATEST) of a Lambda function is a revision with an ID too?

Comment: @Shuzheng: yes, yes and yes. Most methods that create new revisions also accept a reference to the old one to ensure compare-and-swap semantics.